# Download file in background task

Tags: c#, windows-runtime

I need to download a file in a background task. The problem is that the file may be fairly large and I don't know if I'll be able to do it in one run. The way I understand this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh977056) is that the network limit for background tasks is based on the average network speed. Is there any way I can calculate this? What happens when I exceed this limit (I suppose my download just stops)? Is there something that will automatically pause the download when the quota is met?

I have tried using [DownloadOperation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.backgroundtransfer.downloadoperation), but the next time the task is ran no download operations are found by `BackgroundDownloader.GetCurrentDownloadsAsync();` so I cannot resume my download.

Comment: I have made a mistake, sorry. My downloads have their group set and GetCurrentDownloadsAsync() returns only downloads without group. I have fixed this and am testing it at the moment. Will update shortly.

Answer (score 0):

After fixing my code, DownloadOperation works perfectly. From [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.backgroundtransfer.downloadoperation.aspx):

> After app termination, an app should enumerate all existing DownloadOperation instances at next start-up using GetCurrentDownloadsAsync. When a Windows Store app using Background Transfer is terminated, incomplete downloads will persist in the background.

This works in background tasks as well. Just make sure you call the correct overload of GetCurrentDownloadsAsync when resuming. :)